# How get recorde from database with limit SUM value column

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with some customer invoices. I need return some record that `SUM(price)` less than **200 dollar**, this mean return record until total or `sum invoice price < 200$`.

Sometimes i want return latest record back and sometimes from beginning.
I use MYSQL database and php.

```
table
-----------------------
id | customerId | price
1         20        15
2         15        10
3         65        42
4         44        12
5         23        78
6         11        66
7         16        95
8         33        48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend variables for calculating the cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@s := @s + price) as sum_price
      from t cross join
           (select @s := 0) params
      order by id
     ) t
where sum_price < 200;
```

Comment: What is the error?  There is no obvious syntax error in the query.

Comment: @farzad . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: In this query if return 160$ and next recorde is 50 the query stop and not continue for finding recorde with recorde price near 40.

Comment: @farzad . . . The question explicitly states:  "sum invoice price < 200$".  In your example, it would return the 160$, but not the 50$, because the sum would then be 210$.

Answer (score 0):

let HAVING filter your results to those < 200:

```
SELECT SUM(price) as total, customerId
FROM table
GROUP BY customerId
HAVING total < 200
```

**Edit**

So you do not need the customer, but all the records for him: then use query above as a subquery:

```
SELECT maintable.Id, maintable.customerId, maintable.price
FROM table AS maintable 
JOIN (
   SELECT  customerId
   FROM table
   GROUP BY customerId
   HAVING SUM(price) < 200
) subq ON subq.customerId = maintable.customerId
```

Comment: This query return all query with price less than 200 but i want return some recorde that total price of recorde less than 200

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.customerid,
  t.price,
  (SELECT
     sum(price) FROM Table1
   WHERE Id <= t.id) 'CalculatedTotal'
FROM Table t
HAVING CalculatedTotal <=200
```

this query calculates and return rows having total less than 200.

Comment: Your query have Error

Comment: SELECT   t.id,   t.customerid,   t.price ,  (SELECT sum(price) FROM Table1    WHERE Id <= t.id) 'CalculatedTotal' FROM Table1 t HAVING CalculatedTotal <=200;